# Questions and/or recommendations about software & electronic devices related to the outdoors?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we allow questions and/or recommendations about software & electronic devices related to the outdoors?

Typically, any kind of question seeking a shopping recommendation has been off-topic, across the board at Stack Exchange.

As for software questions, I think they should be off-topic, perhaps asked/migrated at/to **[Super User, our site for computer hardware/software](https://superuser.com/)** (full disclosure: I'm a  SU diamond moderator), where well-written, specific [software-rec](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) questions are allowed.

Example question: [Are there any cheap 1:25K electronic maps for the UK or Europe?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/64/are-there-any-cheap-125k-electronic-maps-for-the-uk-or-europe)

What about questions regarding GPS units?  Should those be allowed in the scope of The Great Outdoors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think they should be allowed if they are tied specifically to outdoor activities. GPS have a wide range of outdoor uses, and electronic maps can be very important for trip planning and printing. Meanwhile, the superuser community is less likely to have domain specific knowledge of the types of software that avid outdoor enthusiasts would.

However, if the question is related to problems operating software, I think SU would be a much better fit.